# Android app - after install the market says "The requested item could not be found" .. and I have TWO app icons?

Tags: android, cordova

I just tried to port an app over to android and it all appeared to go great but now when I download the app to my phone (I am wondering if this isnt just an issue with my droid since it was the test dummy) from the market and try and open it FROM THE MARKET...it tells me 'The requested item could not be found."

Furthermore, when I go to my apps...its there ...TWICE!

Yikes!  Has anyone experienced this and can you tell me what to do quickly so I can fix this before this happens to anyone???

The app is 'Isthe it a cow!?' ... ive verified tjat its not just on my phone...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620353/android-app-development-two-icons-getting-created-and-i-only-need-one

I had the <intent-filter> launcher set twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<intent-filter>` launcher set twice in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you see two app icons it means that the package names were different. In the process of porting, you may have accidentally done this. Look into that. An app will override the other only if the package names are exactly the same.

Comment: Ill try that... where do you think I might have changed the names?  My package name is com.digitalfuel.isitacow.. and I see it in my main .java file and my manifest... but those are both the same..?

Comment: app names are set in manifest file. And should correspond to the package name, so your main activity class should be in com.digitalfuel.etcetc package.

Answer (score 0):

If i was in your position, to better help this community answer your question I would post the name of the app and keep my eye on Stackoverflow for a answer.