# Flutter: How to create app shortcuts in home screen programmatically?

Tags: flutter, shortcut

There are similar questions here, I know, but none of them solve my problem.
I want, when my user press send to home screen, to create a shortcut of entire app/choosen screen/ particular functionality in the home screen. How to do that? Please help

Comment: You want to create two app icons, Right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620353/android-app-development-two-icons-getting-created-and-i-only-need-one/25833707
You can change Android manifest in the android folder

Comment: Thanks, @abbas for commenting. But I don't need two app icons. Let me explain my problem with an example; In WhatsUp you can add favorite contacts on the home screen, right?. Or in file browser you can add a shortcut of the file path on the home screen. I want similar functionality. Can I do that with flutter? I am just a beginner, I don't know where to start. Please help me.

Comment: I wish to know if there is some flutter counter part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390528/flutter-add-shortcuts-to-launcher-menu-and-home-screen

Comment: This is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905328/how-to-create-pinnedshortcuts-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873256/how-to-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-in-android-programmatically) link to see how to create home screen shortcut icons in native android. 
Then you can just link it to you flutter app using [MethodChannels](https://medium.com/halkbank-mobile-tech/methodchannel-in-flutter-7dabff9ea9d0)